# Swift 4.2 coalescing while downcasting multiple variables in a single if-let

Tags: swift, default-value, downcast, coalescing

I recently started learning Swift, now I'm trying to safely unwrap multiple variables that come from a JSON response which might contain or not that key.

Example of the JSON response:

```
{
    "products: [{
        "foo": "foo"
        "bar": "bar"
    }, {
        "foo": "foo"
    }]
}
```

Here I'm trying the following:

```
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let safeData = data else { return }

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: safeData, options: .mutableLeaves)
        if let jsonDict = json as? [String : Any] {
            let productArray = jsonDict["products"] as? [[String : Any]]
            for product in productArray! {
                if let foo = product["foo"] as? String, let bar = product["bar"] as? String {
                    let prod = Product(foo: foo, bar: bar)
                    products.append(prod)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print ("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to give `bar` a default value (coalescing) if the value is nil, such as `"Not Available"` in order to display it in a label.

Is it possible? How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 let prod = Product(foo:product["foo"] as? String ?? "Not Available" , bar: product["bar"] as? String ?? "Not Available" )
```

---

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let products: [Product]
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    let foo: String
    let bar: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case foo , bar  
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

         let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)


        do { 
            let foo = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .foo)  
            let bar = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .bar) ?? "Not Available"
            self.init(foo:foo, bar:bar)

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only possible way? My actual `Product` contains around 10 properties, so I wanted to make it clearer having them in their own variables.

Comment: I guess a more clean way is through `Codable`

Comment: You should be using Decodable, not JSONSerialization.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'll look into it @matt. Can you add the `Codable` part into your answer Sh_Khan? I'll accept once I'm allowed to after you add it.

Answer (score 1):

As the Keys in json are `Decodable` friendly, you can use this minimal code,

```
struct ProductResponse: Decodable {
    let products: [Product]
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    let foo: String
    let bar: String?
}

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {
        let productResponse = JSONDecoder().decode(ProductResponse.self, from: data)
        print(productResponse.products.forEach({ print($0.foo)}))
    } catch {
        print ("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Assigning a default value to `bar` at parsing level doesn't seem natural. `Product` is a simple type with just two properties but for a type with tens of properties you will hate implementing the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and `CodingKeys` `enumerations` just because of one or two properties that need a default value.

I would suggest a better approach by introducing an `extension` to `Optional` as below,

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    /// Unwrapped string
    /// `u7d` comes from starting `u` in `Unwrapped`, 
    ///  7 letters in between and last letter `d`.
    public func u7d(_ defaultString: String = "N/A") -> String {
        guard let value = self, value.isEmpty == false else { return defaultString }
        return value
    }
}
```

So now when you want to use a default `value` if this property is `nil`, you can just unwrap by passing that default `value` as below,

```
productResponse.products.forEach({ product in
    print(product.bar.u7d("Not Available"))
})
```

This has some key benefits as below,

- Your `if statement` result will stay as expected when you will compare this optional property with `nil`.
- You can pass different default values at different places without any `if statement`.
- As `UITextField`, `UITextView` and `UILabel` accept `Optional` text and in many cases you will need to show a `placeholder` when the `string` attribute is `nil` from the api response. So in those cases you don't have to re-engineer the `string` attribute to know if it has default value or api returned value.